# Overlapping colour filling with PSTricks

Tags: color, pstricks

Consider the following diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \textbf{\Huge Venn Diagram of Irrational Nonsense}
\end{center}
\vspace{5ex}

\begin{center}
\psset{unit = 2.4}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-1.75)(3.5,4.25)
\psellipse[rot = -50](1.5,0.5)(1.5,3)
\psellipse[rot = 50](-1.5,0.5)(1.5,3)
\psellipse[rot = -50](0,1.8)(1.5,3)
\psellipse[rot = 50](0,1.8)(1.5,3)
\rput(-3.57,1.93){
  \begin{rotate}{45}
    \shortstack[c]{%
      Religious\strut\\[-0.75ex]
      Bollocks\strut}
  \end{rotate}
}
\rput(-2.1,3.2){
  \begin{rotate}{45}
    \shortstack[c]{%
      Quackery\strut\\[-0.75ex]
      Bollocks\strut}
  \end{rotate}
}
\rput(3.07,2.33){
  \begin{rotate}{315}
    \shortstack[c]{%
      Paranormal\strut\\[-0.75ex]
      Bollocks\strut}
  \end{rotate}
}
\rput(1.52,3.78){
  \begin{rotate}{315}
    \shortstack[c]{%
      Pseudoscientific\strut\\[-0.75ex]
      Bollocks\strut}
  \end{rotate}
}
\rput(0,0.5){Scientology}
{\footnotesize
\rput(0.5,0){\shortstack[c]{%
  Psychic\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Surgery\strut}}
\rput(1.5,0.1){Aura Therapy}
\rput(1.7,0.5){Reiki}
\rput(1.9,0.9){Chakra}
\rput(0.6,1){Qi}
\rput(0.9,1.3){Feng Shui}
\rput(1.2,1.6){Past Life Regression}
{\tiny
\rput(2.1,2.43){Ley Lines}
\rput(1.95,2.32){Orgone Energy}
\rput(1.97,2.21){Palmistry}
\rput(1.98,2.1){Orbs}}
\rput(2.9,1.8){Crop Circles}
\rput(3.1,1.5){Ectoplasm}
\rput(3.1,1.2){Telepathy}
\rput(3,0.9){Tarot}
\rput(3,0.6){\shortstack[c]{%
  Crystal\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Power\strut}}
\rput(2.9,0.3){\shortstack[c]{%
  Automaric\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Writing\strut}}
\rput(2.75,0){Geomancy}
\rput(2.55,-0.25){Levitation}
\rput(2.1,-0.5){Remote Writing}
\rput(2,-0.7){Ghosts}
\rput(1.4,-0.7){Psychics}
\rput(1.5,-1){Poltergeist}
\rput(1.2,-1.2){Seances}
\rput(-0.5,-0.5){Exorcism}
\rput(-0.5,-0.8){Ouija Boards}
\rput(-0.5,-1.1){Spiritualism}
\rput(0,-1.4){Stigmata}
\rput(0.5,-0.5){Akashic Record}
\rput(0.5,-0.8){Occult}
\rput(0.5,-1.1){Voodoo}
\rput(-0.5,0){\shortstack[c]{%
  Bible\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Code\strut}}
\rput(-1.9,0.95){\shortstack[c]{%
  Apocalyptic\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Prophecies\strut}}
\rput(-1.7,0.6){Intelligent Design}
\rput(-1.6,0.3){Out of Body Experience}
\rput(-1.5,0){Turin Shroud}
\rput(-1.2,1.6){Antrophosophy}
\rput(-0.8,1.1){Alphabiotics}
\rput(0,3.2){Anti Vaccination}
\rput(-0.4,2.9){Cupping}
\rput(0.4,2.9){Chiropratic}
\rput(0,2.6){Bioharmonics}
\rput(-0.4,2.3){Reflexology}
\rput(0.4,2.3){Rolfing}
\rput(0,2){Applied Kinesiology}
\rput(0,1.75){Ear Candles}
\rput(0,1.5){Detox}
{\scriptsize
\rput(0.7,3.7){Chemtrails}
\rput(1,3.525){Astrology}
\rput(1.3,3.35){Numerology}
\rput(1.6,3.175){Hollow Earth}
\rput(1.8,3){Moon Landing Denial}
\rput(1.8,2.825){Dowsing}
\rput(1.8,2.65){Bigfoot}}
\rput(-0.7,3.6){Shiatsu}
\rput(-1,3.4){Acupuncture}
\rput(-1.3,3.2){Homeopathy}
\rput(-1.6,3){Aromatherapy}
\rput(-1.8,2.8){Ayurvedic Medicine}
{\tiny
\rput(-2.1,2.4){\shortstack[c]{%
  Angel\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Therapy\strut}}
\rput(-1.98,2.15){\shortstack[c]{%
  Faith\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Healing\strut}}}
\rput(-2.8,1.9){Miracles}
\rput(-3,1.6){\shortstack[c]{%
  Religious\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  Fundamentalism\strut}}
\rput(-3.1,1.3){Reincarnation}
\rput(-3.1,1.05){Creationism}
\rput(-3,0.8){Prayer}
\rput(-2.97,0.5){\shortstack[c]{%
  Trans-\strut\\[-0.75ex]
  substantiation\strut}}
\rput(-2.85,0.2){Holy Relics}
\rput(-2.65,-0.1){Angels}
\rput(-2.35,-0.4){The Trinity}
\rput(-1.9,-0.7){Karma}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I colour the diagram in order to get the following output?

[image: wanted]

Note that the specific colours are not important; it's how I get the overlapping colours.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem, but +1 for awesome Venn diagram! 

P.S. [They will sue you!](http://www.southparkstudios.com/clips/155134/go-ahead-sue-me)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a simple solid filling with a small value for `opacity`:

```
[...]
\psset{unit = 2.4,opacity=0.2,fillstyle=solid}
\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-1.75)(3.5,4.25)
\psellipse[rot=-50,fillcolor=blue](1.5,0.5)(1.5,3)
\psellipse[rot = 50,fillcolor=red](-1.5,0.5)(1.5,3)
\psellipse[rot = -50,fillcolor=green](0,1.8)(1.5,3)
\psellipse[rot = 50,fillcolor=yellow](0,1.8)(1.5,3)
[...]
```

[image]